# Show number of API hits on view with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json, api, angular-controller

I am a beginner at Angular JS and trying to understand this concept. I have a JSON API which consist of product list and have used `$hhtp.get` to fetch and show the output in the view.

All i want to understand, if the problem statement asks for showing the number of hits/calls made to API in HTML. How to do that.

Here is my sample code

```
var app = angular.module('FusionApp', []);
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'displayproducts', function ($scope, displayproducts) {
    displayproducts.success(function (data) {
        $scope.show = data.products;
        //get the product count
        $scope.productCount = $scope.show.length;
    });
}]);
```

Here is the HTML view

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
     <div class="form-group">
         <span ng-model="productCount">Product Count: {{productCount}}</span> |
         <span ng-model="apiCount">API Hits:</span>
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Search by Name" /</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate if you guide here. Note `displayProducts` is the factory service call to return the data

Comment: do you want to get number of hits/calls made to API per user session??

Comment: There is a front end design mock up that asks to display the total product count and API hits count on the main page. I am not sure on that You can take both cases with user session and without it as well. What is the difference

Comment: Also note that the API does not have endpoint or key to track of the number of hits that gives back the data..